# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.7.1. gradle build not syncing

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting gradle sync fail. i have updated all the gradle versions to the latest

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.springframework.org/release"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.restlet.com"
        }
        }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.7.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }}allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.springframework.org/release"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.restlet.com"
        }
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }}task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

and this is the exception that I got

Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.7.1.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.7.1/gradle-6.7.1.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.7.1/gradle-6.7.1.pom
- https://maven.springframework.org/release/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.7.1/gradle-6.7.1.pom
- https://maven.restlet.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.7.1/gradle-6.7.1.pom
Required by:
project :
Add google Maven repository and sync project
Open File (3 s 321 ms)